# Failed to connect to 'AAD1' service in SAP HANA Backup using Azure site recovery

Tags: azure, backup, hana, azure-backup-vault

I am using the SAP Hana 2.0 & trying to implement the SAP HANA backup using the Azure Recovery vault.

For that, I have to run the file "msawb-plugin-config-com-sap-hana.sh". So it was showing the error as Failed to connect AAD1 service.

Anyone knows the issue. please resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue too. I'm working with SAP Hana running on a SUSE 15sp1 Azure VM, with network connectivity established by the use of NSG service tags as from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-sap-hana-database.

Looking inside the script I noticed that a curl request is used to run connectivity checks

```
curl --silent --output /dev/null --location --request "HEAD" "https://login.windows.net/" --write-out "%{http_code}\n"
```

If I run curl manually, changing the options in order to make it display the whole of the command output, it returns the following:

```
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

This error is reported as a closed issue on the curl Github repo (https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4409). It looks like if it would be solved by subsequent curl release.

Mine is 7.60.0. Latest is 7.73.0. Unfortunately 7.60 seems to be the latest available in SUSE repos and I do not want to intall not officially approved packages on a production system.

So in my case the only way out would be to run the script with the `--skip-network-checks` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

We just fixed this issue in the latest version of script updated yesterday. Can you please re-check with the latest version?

Comment: To users who downvoted the answer, can you please share which version of script you are using? We want to re-check since we removed curl dependency for AAD URL check. Thanks in advance.